# Js - .travis.yml - для чего этот файл?

Tags: тестирование, travis-ci

Не первый раз встречаю в исходниках библиотек файл `.travis.yml`. Понял, что он связан с тестированием, `Travis CI` и `github`'ом. Можете подробно рассказать как работает этот файл и что делает `Travis CI`?

Comment: В документации Travis CI всё есть, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis-ci работает с сервисом github.com, поэтому первым делом необходимо выложить туда исходный код своего проекта. За исключением мелких технических настроек (вроде установки хуков в репозитории), весь процесс сводится к описанию различных опций в файле .travis.yml. В нем нужно описать на каком языке работает проект, какие версии языка необходимо использовать (можно сразу все), среды окружения (здесь приведен пример такого файла для ruby). Данный файл необходимо разместить в корне github-репозитория.

Если настройка прошла успешно, то travis-ci начинает непрерывно тестировать проект, отображая при этом текущий статус: красный цвет (возникли проблемы при тестировании), желтый (есть предупреждения) и зеленый (все тесты пройдены успешно). Помимо статуса можно увидеть: сообщение об ошибке или предупреждение, если что-то пошло не так; последний коммит и его автора; историю сборок и т.д. В целом интерфейс достаточно информативен и понятен. Помимо этого, travis-ci будет оповещать о проблемах по электронной почте.

[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/140344/)